# How to get automatic keyboard layout switching in windows 10

Tags: skype, keyboard-layout, windows-10

After updating to Windows 10 I have noticed that I don't have automatic keyboard layout switching anymore. In Windows 7 when I typed in skype e.g. in one language it remembered the choice and did revert to it any time I focused skype. I am not sure if it was windows feature or skype feature, (I think Windows), but I would like to have it back in Windows 10, any ideas on how to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the setting that is responsible for this
[image]